# Ehcache automatic key generation and @Cacheable spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, pojo, method-parameters

Does anybody know how the default key generation for Ehcache works? If I have the following method:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = CACHE_KEY) // CACHE_KEY is static final field.
public List<DataObject> list(
    int firstRecord, int maxRecords, int pageSize, FilterObject filter) {
    ....
}
```

where `FilterObject` is a custom POJO, what should I expect to be the actual cache key?

What I am observing is when using different `FilterObject` instances *and not changing the other arguments* of my method call, it always produces the same result - the first call's result is cached and returned.

Probably it is the `FilterObject` POJO which causes the behaviour - I suppose it is either some serialization, or `.toString()` issue, because I haven't overridden the relevant methods.

Still I was unable to find exact information on how the cache key for such method is being formed both in Ehcache's website and in the `@Cacheable` annotation documentation.
I'd appreciate any information and recommendations on this topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the default key generator

```
public class DefaultKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

public static final int NO_PARAM_KEY = 0;
public static final int NULL_PARAM_KEY = 53;

public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
    if (params.length == 1) {
        return (params[0] == null ? NULL_PARAM_KEY : params[0]);
    }
    if (params.length == 0) {
        return NO_PARAM_KEY;
    }
    int hashCode = 17;
    for (Object object : params) {
        hashCode = 31 * hashCode + (object == null ? NULL_PARAM_KEY : object.hashCode());
    }
    return Integer.valueOf(hashCode);
}

}
```

As you can see, it combines the hash-codes of each method parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this explains the behavior I have observed. Also the code above turns out to be quite self-describing :)

Comment: this seems wrong, why should any method, in any class, all get a key of zero if the method has no parameters? I would assume it would be at least get a unique key, my assumption cost me a bit of time wondering why my new caching wasn't working

Comment: I believe that some notes regarding the correctness of algorithm should be added

Answer (score 5):

Everything is explained in Spring [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html), namely in:

#### [28.3.1.1 Default Key Generation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key):

> [...]
>
> - If more the one param is given, return a key **computed from the hashes of all parameters**.
>
> To provide a different default key generator, one needs to implement the `org.springframework.cache.KeyGenerator` interface. Once configured, the generator will be used for each declaration that doesn not specify its own key generation strategy (see below).

and below:

#### [28.3.1.2 Custom Key Generation Declaration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key):

> [...] the @Cacheable annotation allows the user to specify how the key is generated through its key attribute. The developer can use SpEL to pick the arguments of interest[...]

And an example from the docs:

```
@Cacheable(value="books", key="#isbn.rawNumber")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

So in your case you should simply implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `FilterObject`. Decent IDE can generate them for you.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't looked at spring's documentation for this. Now the odd behavior is explained.

Comment: This explanation corresponds with Spring cache, but the question is about ehcache, with has no key option!